# open the image in windows photo viewer by clicking on picturebox1 c#

Tags: c#, windows, image, picturebox

I have a project with SQlite database . I save images in folder " pics " ( into debug folder) & their name in the database ( column "docpic") . When I click in a row , related image retrieve the image from database to picturebox1 . i want open the image ( in picturebox1 ) by windows photo viewer by clicking on picturebox1 .
how can do this ?

i use this codes in picturebox1 click event but thats not work :

```
if (pictureBox1.Tag != null)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process imageViewerProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    imageViewerProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    imageViewerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
    imageViewerProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =
            @"C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen "
                               + pictureBox1.Tag.ToString();
    imageViewerProcess.Start();
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know on what Windows version (and if 32/64 bits) will it run?

Comment: my windows is 64 bit

Comment: What Windows are you using? Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1, 10 ?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit

Comment: can anybody help please ?

Comment: @Tony windows 7 64 bit