# open photo by windows photo viewer y clicking on a label with image name c#

Tags: c#, windows, label, photo, viewer

I have a project with SQlite database . I save images in folder " scan " ( into debug folder) & their name in the database ( column "docpic") . When I click in a row , related image name retrieve the image name from database to label10.text (label10.text = image.jpg ). i want open the images (that shows there name in label10.text) with windows photo viewer by clicking on label10 & using label10.text instead image.jag (name of image) . how can do this ?

Comment: please clear your question

Comment: @Joji Thomas Eapen thank u for your comment . but u cant understand the question or cant understand the answer ?

Comment: both, the question and your explanation, provide the sample code which u tried also

Comment: im busy for this some days friend . thats not so esay that seems for me . if you have sample code , show me that please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676443/open-the-image-in-windows-photo-viewer-by-clicking-on-picturebox1-c-sharp/42677824?noredirect=1#comment72492519_42677824

Comment: at above link i quest my question in another way . but answers dont work !

Comment: ok letme chck and replay to u.